# The Number Of Fractional Digits Is Out Of Range - Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am using ajax numeric updown extender control but it is raising an exception "**The Number Of Fractional Digits Is Out Of Range**" when i change values using the up or down buttons. The structure of my web page is shown below :

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>        
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnMaxRowsUp" runat="server" Height="8px" 
                             ImageUrl="~/Images/up.jpg" Width="8px" CausesValidation="False" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnMaxRowsDown" runat="server" Height="8px" 
                             ImageUrl="~/Images/down.jpg" Width="8px" CausesValidation="False" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:NumericUpDownExtender ID="nudExMaxRows" runat="server"
                            TargetControlID="txtBox" 
                            TargetButtonDownID="ibtnMaxRowsDown" 
                            TargetButtonUpID="ibtnMaxRowsUp"
                            Minimum="500000" Maximum="10000000" Step="100000"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Can any one suggest me the solution for solving this problem? Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you experience this error:

[NumericUpDown Extender IE Error - "The number of fractional digits is out of range"](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/13114)